# Remove spaces from a string of text in clipboard

Tags: clipboard, trim, spaces

This is maybe a weird request but hear me out:

I have a huge database at my shop containing product codes, like `87 445 G 6` which I need to check for availability on a supplier's website. The problem is, the supplier's website consists of a web form in which I have to enter the code without spaces, so imagine that I have to manually delete spaces every time I paste a code or write it manually without.
I can't edit the database from which I copy the codes.

I wonder if some sort of plugin, script, or trick can be used directly in browser on the supplier's web form, or some software to modify how the windows clipboard works, maybe some option to copy text without spaces. Using Windows XP.

Comment: What kind of field do you enter into? A little text field or a big text box?

Comment: How do you get the data from the database? Do you have any ability to script things with a database client or are you pulling this off a web interface to your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has probably moved on, but for anyone else looking here, my approach was to tackle this from the windows clipboard side.

For background: I keep a list of my credit card info in Keepass.  Sometimes (poorly coded) shopping cart checkout forms don't like spaces in between card numbers.  I like storing them with spaces since it's easier to read off that way.

There's various Windows clipboard utilites out there, but it took me a while to find one that could do some processing on the clipboard contents and pasting it out - [Clipboard Help and Spell](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/clipboardhelpandspell/)

The program has a way to "save" a bunch of text transformations, and even assign the action to a hotkey.

For reference, my "Find and Replace" action is to find "\s" (without quotes) and leave the Replace textbox empty.  "\s" will match whitespace character.

Comment: I found a better program if anyone googling is looking for a way to "scrub" whitespace from the beginning and end of copied text automatically: http://www.clipboardfusion.com/

Answer (score 1):

## Use the javascript console

You could use the javascript console for your browser to edit the textarea after you paste.

### Using Google Chrome (or Firefox)

Paste your text in the text area.

Right click the text area and click `Inspect Element`

[image: Inspect Element]

Look at the id for the element

[image: id]

Now switch to the console view

[image: console]

then run these lines (making sure to replace with `'the-id'` with your id)

```
var my_text_area = document.getElementById('the-id'); // Put your id in here
my_text_area.value = my_text_area.value.replace(/ /g,"") // Deletes just spaces
```

It's even simpler if you have access to jQuery:

```
$('#the-id').val($('#the-id').val().replace(/ /g, ""))
```

The `replace` function is simply using regular expressions to convert spaces to nothing. If you want to replace all whitespace (including newlines) you would use `.replace(/\s/g,"")`.

For firefox, the names are the same but the UI is a little bit different.

[image: Firefox inspect element]

## Use [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

You can either write a [greasemonkey plugin](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/151680) or try to find one that fits your needs.

Comment: Well both methods give me an error saying that the value is NULL. That is maybe because the .value of the textfield when the page is loaded is empty. Even if I type a code and then run the command it still gives value NULL.

Comment: Oh! You need to add your text first. This function replaces whatever text is in the field.

Comment: What if I can modify the page of the database I have ? 
These codes are listed between the html tags `<nobr>78 G 8887</nobr>`
If I can create a JS function to list these without spaces then it saves me of trimming manually after pasting them in.

I tried this:

`x = new Array();

x = document.getElementsByTagName("nobr");

alert(x[1].innerHTML);`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, aren't you pasting something in? The textarea should be editable then. If you truly have to do it outside of there, perhaps using notepad++ to do search and replace is a better option.

Comment: Oh the codes are listed that way? Yeah, changing the javascript on the page you pull from is probably even better. Care to post more code (like an outer tag or at least a bigger snippet) in your question above?

Comment: Just found out the problem is much more complicated. It seems that the page from wich I pull the codes is made with iframes, and not from the same domain.

The codes are listed in a table, between `<nobr> </nobr>` tags 

Here is a bigger snipper

`<div class="artcl">
   <a href="/default.aspx?32=" onfocus="this.blur();" onclick="javascript:openColorboxWithIFrame(this.href, '90%', '90%');return false;" title="Article code"><nobr>ACC 51920</nobr></a>
</div>`

That is how they are listed on the page

Comment: Each one is within their own div? What's the outer container?

Comment: Each one within itw own div.
The structure is like this:
<div id content>
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div>
    <div class="artcl">
     <a><nobr>####</nobr></a>